# Why can I compare to a uniqueidentifer string long than it should be?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why is this possible? I really don't understand why. I can write anything I want behind the GUID itself and the comparison does not fail. Is this a intented "failsafe" behavior?

The "id" field is a uniqueidentifier field.

[image]

Comment: What is `id`? I suspect it's not a GUID but a fixed-width `char`, which is already a problem

Comment: It is a uniqueidentifier field.

Comment: Don't describe the table. Post the table schema, query and results as text others can copy and test

Comment: `select 1 where cast('088BFCD5-7411-4BCB-9C19-97ED920FE10C' as uniqueidentifier) = '088BFCD5-7411-4BCB-9C19-97ED920FE10Cbatman'` returns one row, so yeah, sql server does some sort of mangling of the right side. You can CAST the right string to UID to get correct behaviour

Comment: The query  isn't comparing GUIDs to GUIDs, but GUID to text. One or the other values will have to be converted to a common type. [This is actually documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#converting-uniqueidentifier-data): `The uniqueidentifier type is considered a character type for the purposes of conversion from a character expression, and therefore is subject to the truncation rules for converting to a character type.`

Comment: Continuing `That is, when character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, values that are too long for the new data type are truncated.  See the Examples section.` People rarely type GUIDs which is why this gets forgotten.

Comment: "People rarely type GUIDs". Sure. But they copy/paste them _all the time_.

Answer (score 4):

The query isn't comparing GUIDs to GUIDs, but GUID to text. One or the other values will have to be converted to a common type. [This is actually documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#converting-uniqueidentifier-data):

> The uniqueidentifier type is considered a character type for the purposes of conversion from a character expression, and therefore is subject to the truncation rules for converting to a character type. That is, when character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, values that are too long for the new data type are truncated. **See the Examples section.**

Emphasis mine - the docs actually have examples for this and yet, we all forget about this.

The reason is that people rarely store or type GUIDs as text. A GUID is 16 bytes but any string representation is at least 32 characters. GUID-generating functions in both databases (eg NEWID, NEWSEQUENTIALID) and languages (eg C#'s Guid.NewGuid()) produce bytes, or binary types, not text.

I'm pretty sure I'll forget this by next week and get surprised all over again by the next similar question.

Comment: Yes! And it also works this way [even if you declare as guid and assign a string](https://dbfiddle.uk/UrvXEVpi).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Even more weirdly, it even works when you use ODBC format https://dbfiddle.uk/d80ZlnSN

Comment: But the ANSI standard is to pad, not truncate, and T-SQL would actually pad the string if there was no cast. Now I'm surprised, docs or no docs. I wonder what Joe Celko would say.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly strange. It's a combination of normal truncation behaviour - eg, `declare @short char(1) = 'ab';`, followed by an implicit conversion along normal precedence rules. This makes particular sense when considering the effect on query plans - to seek on the guid we need to turn the character expression into a guid, we certainly don't want to convert the column data to varchar and pad it to match the length of the character expression and then scan.